# Parse "" and null commonly and check for empty field in iphone

Tags: iphone, json, ios5

This below is a JSON output I got in `NSDictionary`.

Can anyone say a method to recognize `""` value and null value commonly? I am trying to check the value is empty or not and also assign it to a `UIlabel`.

```
User =     {
        address = "";
        birthday = "<null>";
        gender = 0;
        "mobile_number" = "<null>";
        name = ambili;
        "phone_number" = "";
        picture = "http://lb.fo********inds.com/images/users/profile_pics/no_picture.jpg";
    };
    status = OK;
}
```

Comment: check for strings using string comparison

Comment: already having 2 other comparisons like cell row index path and row selection. additional this 2 comparison for 6 rows make code very much trouble some.  it is a json value.

Comment: it would be batter if you manage from the back-end side by don't allowing <null> to send in json

Answer (score 0):

you can check if a string is equal to another with following:

```
if ([myString isEqualToString:@""] || [myString isEqualToString:@"<null>"]) {
    NSLog(@"empty or null");
}
```

Comment: i already having 2 other comparison on this field and 2 more checking is troublesome. is there any generalized solution?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using this multiple times, it would be a good candidate for a class extension.  When you use a class extension, you can use custom functions like:

```
if ([birthday hasJSONData])
{
    // Do something
}
```

To do this, you create a new NSString class extension that looks like this:

**Header file (NSString+Kurian_Utils.h):**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (Kurian_Utils)

- (BOOL)hasJSONData;

@end
```

**Implementation file (NSString+Kurian_Utils.m):**

```
#import "NSString+Kurian_Utils.h"

@implementation NSString (Kurian_Utils)

// If the NSString is nil, calling this function will return NO because it is sent to nil.
 - (BOOL)hasJSONData
{
    if ([self length] == 0)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    if ([self localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:@"<null>"] == NSOrderedSame)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Then just `#import "NSString+Kurian_Utils.h"` in the file where you want to use `hasJSONData`.

Answer (score 0):

at last i findout a simple way and it working well. i glad to share it to u all.

```
 id phoneString = [Contentds valueForKeyPath:@"User.phone"];
    if (phoneString != [NSNull null])
    {
    label.text=[Contentds valueForKeyPath:@"User.phone"];
    }
```

Comment: This will not be correct for a value containing "<null>" or an empty string.  Also, you are comparing the pointer value and not the actual contents of the string.  Please do not compare strings this way, as it will cause very odd and hard to track down errors in the future!

Comment: thanks Inafziger for the right information. but for me it checking everything fine in my code that i shown in the above. what is the future risk here?

Comment: When you compare with == you are checking to see if the two objects point to the same place in memory.  This **sometimes** works for different objects because iOS **sometimes** caches objects that have the same value into the same object. This is **NOT** guaranteed though, and sometimes is not done, depending on how the objects are created.  Worse, this behavior could change at any point in the future and break your program, because it is an undocumented "feature".